# Can't get an R loop to execute

Tags: r

I am starting in R and trying to get this loop to execute. I am trying to get the loop to calculate consecutive distances between coordinates using a function (Vincenty's formula). 'Distfunc' is the file to the function. The function is then called up by 'x' below. All I want then is a data frame or a list of the distances between coordinates. Greatful of any help!

```
Distfunc <- source("F://Distfunc.R")
for (i in length(Radians)) {
    LatRad1 <- Radians[i,1]
    LongRad1 <- Radians[i,2]
    LatRad2 <- Radians[i+1,1]
    LongRad2 <- Radians[i+1,2]
    x <- gcd.vif(LongRad1, LatRad1, LongRad2, LatRad2) 
    print(data.frame(x[i]))
}
```

Comment: It may not solve everything, but the most obvious thing to me is that you should use `for (i in 1:length(Radians)){` or `for (1 in seq_along(Radians)){`

Comment: @Benjamin: Actually, `for (i in seq_along(Radians)){`

Comment: Yeah, what @tguzella said. (Big difference between `i` and `1`)

Comment: @Benjamin, Well, actually that is not a good idea, since the code needs the value at row `i + 1`. Therefore, the for loop should be: `for (i in seq(1, nrow(Radians) - 1)) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without a good description of the problem you are facing and a proper reproducible example it is very difficult to provide any good insight. To start off, see [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

There are many things that are not clear in the way you are doing things. First of all, why assign the results of `source(...)` to the variable `Distfunc`?

Anyways, here is some code that I put together in trying to understand this; it runs without problems, but it is not clear that it accomplishes what you expect (since you don't provide much information). In particular, the codet uses the implementation for function `gcd.vif` by Mario Pineda-Krch (http://www.r-bloggers.com/great-circle-distance-calculations-in-r/). The code below is aimed at clarity, since you mention that you are starting in R.

```
# Calculates the geodesic distance between two points specified by radian latitude/longitude using
# Vincenty inverse formula for ellipsoids (vif)
# By Mario Pineda-Krch (http://www.r-bloggers.com/great-circle-distance-calculations-in-r/)
gcd.vif <- function(long1, lat1, long2, lat2) {

    # WGS-84 ellipsoid parameters
    a <- 6378137 # length of major axis of the ellipsoid (radius at equator)
    b <- 6356752.314245 # ength of minor axis of the ellipsoid (radius at the poles)
    f <- 1/298.257223563 # flattening of the ellipsoid

    L <- long2-long1 # difference in longitude
    U1 <- atan((1-f) * tan(lat1)) # reduced latitude
    U2 <- atan((1-f) * tan(lat2)) # reduced latitude
    sinU1 <- sin(U1)
    cosU1 <- cos(U1)
    sinU2 <- sin(U2)
    cosU2 <- cos(U2)

    cosSqAlpha <- NULL
    sinSigma <- NULL
    cosSigma <- NULL
    cos2SigmaM <- NULL
    sigma <- NULL

    lambda <- L
    lambdaP <- 0
    iterLimit <- 100
    while (abs(lambda-lambdaP) > 1e-12 & iterLimit>0) {
        sinLambda <- sin(lambda)
        cosLambda <- cos(lambda)
        sinSigma <- sqrt( (cosU2*sinLambda) * (cosU2*sinLambda) +
            (cosU1*sinU2-sinU1*cosU2*cosLambda) * (cosU1*sinU2-sinU1*cosU2*cosLambda) )
        if (sinSigma==0) return(0)  # Co-incident points
        cosSigma <- sinU1*sinU2 + cosU1*cosU2*cosLambda
        sigma <- atan2(sinSigma, cosSigma)
        sinAlpha <- cosU1 * cosU2 * sinLambda / sinSigma
        cosSqAlpha <- 1 - sinAlpha*sinAlpha
        cos2SigmaM <- cosSigma - 2*sinU1*sinU2/cosSqAlpha
        if (is.na(cos2SigmaM)) cos2SigmaM <- 0  # Equatorial line: cosSqAlpha=0
        C <- f/16*cosSqAlpha*(4+f*(4-3*cosSqAlpha))
        lambdaP <- lambda
        lambda <- L + (1-C) * f * sinAlpha *
            (sigma + C*sinSigma*(cos2SigmaM+C*cosSigma*(-1+2*cos2SigmaM*cos2SigmaM)))
        iterLimit <- iterLimit - 1
    }
    if (iterLimit==0) return(NA)  # formula failed to converge
    uSq <- cosSqAlpha * (a*a - b*b) / (b*b)
    A <- 1 + uSq/16384*(4096+uSq*(-768+uSq*(320-175*uSq)))
    B <- uSq/1024 * (256+uSq*(-128+uSq*(74-47*uSq)))
    deltaSigma = B*sinSigma*(cos2SigmaM+B/4*(cosSigma*(-1+2*cos2SigmaM^2) -
        B/6*cos2SigmaM*(-3+4*sinSigma^2)*(-3+4*cos2SigmaM^2)))
    s <- b*A*(sigma-deltaSigma) / 1000
    return(s) # Distance in km
}

# Initialize the variable 'Radians' with random data
Radians <- matrix(runif(20, min = 0, max = 2 * pi), ncol = 2)

lst <- list() # temporary list to store the results
for (i in seq(1, nrow(Radians) - 1)) { # loop through each row of the 'Radians' matrix
    LatRad1 <- Radians[i, 1]
    LongRad1 <- Radians[i, 2]
    LatRad2 <- Radians[i + 1, 1]
    LongRad2 <- Radians[i + 1, 2]
    gcd_vif <- gcd.vif(LongRad1, LatRad1, LongRad2, LatRad2)

    # Store the input data and the results
    lst[[i]] <- c(
        latitude_position_1 = LatRad1, 
        longtude_position_1 = LongRad1, 
        latitude_position_2 = LatRad2, 
        longtude_position_2 = LongRad2, 
        GCD = gcd_vif
    )
}
Results <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst)) # store the input data and the results in a data frame
```

Comment: Thank you very much this has been really helpful!